# Loading static files referenced by other static files in django

Tags: python, django

In my Python Django project I have a static html file (map.html). Inside this html file other static files are referenced. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script>L_PREFER_CANVAS = false; L_NO_TOUCH = false; L_DISABLE_3D = false;</script>
    <script src="mfiles/leaflet_002.js"></script>
    <script src="mfiles/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="mfiles/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="mfiles/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mfiles/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mfiles/bootstrap.css">

...
```

The static html file is referenced from a template file (index.html) using django template language as so:

```
{% load static %}
<iframe src="{% static "map.html" %}" id="iframemap" style="top:0;left: 0;width:100%;height: 100%; position: absolute; border: none;">
```

The problem is django can't find the static files (mfiles/leaflet_002.js etc.) referenced in the static html file (map.html), because in this html file (map.html), django template language cannot be used so django doesn't find path to these files.

To make my architecture clean I present this simple diagram:

django_template_file *----references---->* map.html (static, loads fine) *----references---->* mfiles/*.js etc. (PROBLEM django doesn't see those files)

How can I tell django to look also in m_app/static/mfiles/* and not just to m_app/static/?

Even though the static files in m_app/static/mfiles/ are referenced only from other static files located in m_app/static/ (and loaded correctly)?

Relevant part of the file structure:

```
m_project
|______> m_app
    |______> __pychache__
    |______> migrations
    |______> static
            |______> m_files ("this folder is referenced in map.html and django doens't see it")
                |______> leaflet_002.js 
                |______> ...
            |______> map.html ("this is the static html file referenced from template index.html")
    |______> templates
        |______> m_app
            |______> index.html ("this is the template file I am talking about above")
    |______> __init__.py
    |______> admin.py
    |______> apps.py
    |______> models.py
    |______> tests.py
    |______> urls.py
    |______> views.py
|______> m_project
    |______> __pychache__
    |______> __init__.py
    |______> settings.py
    |______> urls.py
    |______> wsgi.py
|______> db.sqlite3
|______> manage.py
```

Comment: can you show the (relevant parts of the) file hierarchy?

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip. See above.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't have the `{% load staticfiles %}` in your `index.html` ?

```
# index.html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <script src='{% static "mfiles/leaflet_002.js" %} '></script>
    ...

# django settings
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'),
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'm_app', 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Done. See above.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Should I tweak with STATIC_URL = '/static/' ? 
The errors I get are in this format: ´[19/Jun/2018 08:16:55] "GET /static/m_files/550_007.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1687´

Comment: i modify it again ca you try this :)

Comment: This is not possible. I have added some clarification to my question. The line <script src="mfiles/leaflet_002.js"></script> is not in index.html, but in map.html, where django template language cannot be used. (I have tried it)